# Django: can I omit ".save(commit=False)" in this case?

Tags: python, django, modelform

Here's the snippet from a view function for ModelForm in Django:

```
if form.is_valid():
    new_entry = form.save(commit=False)
    new_entry.topic = topic
    new_entry.save()
```

Would substituting this code with the following one have the same effect?:

```
if form.is_valid():
    form.topic = topic
    form.save()
```

If so, what is the use of creating `new_entry` object like in the first example?

Comment: Does the `form` object have attribute `topic`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Would substituting this code with the following one have the same effect?

Obviously not - your `form` object is not the model instance returned by `form.save()`. Your current (first snippet) solution is the official canonical solution, the other option would be to pass the topic to the form and override your form's `save()` method to take care of it:

```
# yourforms.py
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):

    # your existing code here

    def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
        # if "topic" is required for your model, 
        # you may want to either have a default value
        # for "topic" or raise if it's not passed.
        self.topic = kw.pop("topic", None)
        super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kw)

   def save(self, commit=False):
       instance = super(MyForm, self).save(commit=commit)
       instance.topic = self.topic
       if commit:
           instance.save()
       return instance
```

And in your view:

```
# your existing code here    
form = MyForm(request.POST, ..., topic=topic)
if form.is_valid():
    new_entry = form.save()
```

As you can see it doesn't make the code any simpler overall - you actually have (a bit) more to add to the form than you save in the view - but at least it makes the view code cleaner (IMHO).

Note that in this case the `new_entry` variable is only useful if you need it later in the view, else you can dispense with it.

Comment: Thanks Bruno. The first code I posted is a book excerpt for adding new entry in  a topic on a blog site. It also has an example for adding new topic, and it uses just `if form.is_valid: form.save()`: do I understand correcty that in this scenario we can get away without creating an instance and using `commit=false`, because we don' assign any attribute to the form?

Comment: I'm afraid you do not understand correctly. Please read the FineManual (the official doc I mean, not "some book") to understand what `commit=False` means and why it's used in your first snippet.

Answer (score 3):

> Would substituting this code with the following one have the same
>   effect?:

No, form.save returns an instance of the Model, setting form.topic do not change this model. What you can do is this:

```
if form.is_valid():
    form.instance.topic = topic
    new_entry = form.save()
```

but make sure you don't have `topic` as a field in your form, otherwise the .save will probably override what you just set.

Another approach would be to just pass an instance with a topic to the form.

```
instance = MyModel(topic=topic)
form = MyForm(request.POST, instance=instance)
if form.is_valid():
    new_entry = form.save()
```

Comment: what if `form.instance` is `None`. We will get an error saying  `NoneType object has no attribute 'topic'`

Comment: Model forms aways create an instance.